# How to add delay into postgresql_database creation after aws_db_instance

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform

I'm using Terraform to deploy a database server with an initial database and user.

The Terraform files are setup fine AFAICS, but the postgresql_role and postgresql_database actions fails because the database (Amazon RDS) is still being setup when they're called.

Is there a Terraform way to add a forced wait in? Or an explicit check to see whether the database is available?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`local-exec` provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) to implement a wait easily enough:

```
variable "database_delay" { default = 60 }

resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "postgres"
  engine_version       = "9.6.1"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "mydb"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name = "my_database_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name = "postgres9.6"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
     command = "sleep ${var.database_delay}"
  }
}
```

In the above example I've set it to simply wait for 60 seconds when creating a database instance before moving on to any other dependent resources/modules (such as the progresql_database resource). Obviously you still need to make sure there is a dependency chain that Terraform can follow to know that it has to complete the `aws_db_instance` creation first.